# How to show second button on pressing first one in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, custom-keyboard

I am new at iPhone programming (Objective C). I wanted to make button which will be visible on long pressing on another button. Just like system keyboard style. I should choose first or second button by holding my finger on them :-) How can I do this, I could not find tutorials. Thanks

Comment: look for [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer `](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer?language=objc)

Answer (score 1):

create and attach the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` instance to your `UIButton`.

```
-(IBAction)SelectImage:(id)sender
{
      UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressMethod:)];
      [self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}
```

Then create the method that handles the gesture

```
- (void)longPressMethod:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture 
{
     if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) 
     {
          NSLog(@"Long Press");
          //Do your code here what you want to perform
     }
}
```